# why list slices in right-to-left direction returns empty list?

Tags: python

I've a list say, `sample_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`.

Now, when I try to access:

```
print(sample_list[-2:2])
```

or,

```
print(sample_list[-3:-7])
```

In both cases, I get an empty list.

Should not it print at-least `[6,7]` or `[5,6,7]` respectively, following left-to-right convention?

I know, I'm doing something wrong semantic-wise.

(trying to print the list in right-to-left direction?)

I would like to understand the logic behind empty list. What is happening here?

Comment: Hint: What does it print if you do `sample_list[-2:]`? Also have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation)

Comment: In `sample_list[x:y]`, the index x is the lower bound and y is the upper. you're doing `sampe_list[-2:2]`, but in the list the element at index 2 comes first.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid the link is certainly helpful. In fact, one of the post somewhat answers my doubt on why I'm getting empty lists rather than an error:
"Python is kind to the programmer ( if there are fewer items than you ask for. For example, if you ask for a[:-2] and a only contains one element,) you get an empty list instead of an error."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that indexes start at 0:

```
sample_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
#              0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

When you do `sample_list[-2:2]`, you're trying to get the second last element to the third element.

But you can't just go from negative to positive (unless you add in a negative step). If you wish to obtain a reversed list, then add a `step`:

```
>>> print sample_list[2:-2][::-1]
[5, 4, 3]
```

This is the same problem with your second example. You're trying to go backwards with negative indicies, but you can't... unless... you add in a negative step!:

```
>>> print sample_list[-3:-7:-1]
[5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to slice from right to left, you need to provide a negative `step`: `sample_list[-2:2:-1]`. This will also reverse the order of the values.

And a slice like `[-2:2]` isn't meaningless. If you do `sample_list[-2:2]` on a list of length two, you'd get a copy of the whole thing. In a list of length three, you'll get a slice with only the middle element. It's only for lists of length 4 or larger, you get an empty slice. If they reversed themselves automatically, then some of those cases would be ambiguous.

Edit: Let me try to make a more comprehensive explanation.

Python's slice syntax is implemented by `slice` objects. That is, `L[start:stop:step]` is equivalent to `L[slice(start, stop, step)]`. (Well, this is how  it works in Python 3. For backwards compatibility reasons Python 2 also has an older approach, using `__getslice__` and `__setslice__` methods, but the newer way with `slice` objects works too.)

When you take a slice or a list or tuple, you always get elements starting with the index `start` and continuing up until the element just before `stop`. The `step` parameter describes the size of the steps taken, with `2` meaning every other value, and `-1` meaning steps in reverse.

Another way of thinking of it is that a slice `L[start:stop:step]` is almost equivalent to the list comprehension `[L[i] for i in range(start, stop, step)]`. The differences are only in what happens when some of the values are negative or not provided.

The rule for handling negative values is easy (and it's the same as for non-slice indexing). For `start` and `stop`, just add the length of the sequence to any negative value. So, for positive `x` and `y`, the slice `L[-x:-y]` is exactly equivalent to `L[len(L)-x:len(L)-y]`. Negative `step` values don't get transformed.

Unlike regular indexing, slicing never raises exceptions for indexes out of range. If indexes are invalid, you may get an empty result, or just fewer values than the slice was asking for.

Not all arguments to a slice are required. A `slice` object's constructor assigns `None` as default values for any argument not provided. What those `None`s mean for `start` and `stop` differs depending on the sign of `step`, and also on the dimensions of the list that's being sliced.

If `step` is `None` it is always treated as if it was `1`. If `step` is positive (or `None`), a `start` value of `None` is treated as if it was `0` and a `stop` value of `None` is treated like `len(L)`. If `step` is negative, a `start` value of `None` is treated as `-1` and `stop` value of `None` is treated as `-len(L)-1`.

So, to circle back to your question, when you do the slice `sample_list[-2:2]`, several things happen:

First off, a `slice` object is created, as if you did `slice(-2, 2)`. That slice object will have a `step` of `None`, since you didn't provide a third value.

Next, the `slice` is passed to the list and the values are interpreted. Since `step` was `None`, the default of `1` is used. Since `start` is negative, the length of the list is added to it.

Finally, the results are figured out. For your example list with seven values, you get the equivalent of `[sample_list[i] for i in range(5, 2, 1)]`. Since the range is empty, the slice is too.

Depending on what you wanted, you can fix this in a few different ways. You could leave it be and you'll get results only for very short source lists, where `len(L)-2` is less than `2`. Alternately, you could swap the order of your first two arguments, and get the result `[3,4,5]`. Or you could add a negative `step` and slice from right to left, resulting in `[6, 5, 4]`.